# How to write query to search data between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

In database I have following data :

```
From date : 2016-09-01 06:00:00
To date : 2016-09-04 08:00:00
```

If I search from '08/01/2016 00:00:00' To '09/05/2016 00:00:00' It is giving me above result.

But problem is if I search it from '08/01/2016 00:00:00' to '09/02/2016 00:00:00' It is Not showing me above result.

My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM car_availability as c , car_trip_availability as ct
WHERE c.car_id = ct.car_id 
AND c.car_category_id IN ($car_category_id_list)
AND c.from_date_time >= :from_date_time
AND c.to_date_time <= :to_date_time
AND c.is_booked = :is_booked
AND ct.trip_type_id =:trip_type_id
AND ct.from_location_id =:from_location_id
AND ct.to_location_id = :to_location_id
```

Comment: hint: use mysql between

Comment: you are using datetime as a datatype for that columns?

Comment: yes I am using datetime

Comment: you have to use dateformat for this , and date in both side must be in same format

Comment: @Ninad , you got my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; always use `JOIN`.

Your logic for an overlap is not correct.  See the last two lines below:

```
SELECT *
FROM car_availability c JOIN
     car_trip_availability ct
     ON c.car_id = ct.car_id 
WHERE c.car_category_id IN ($car_category_id_list) AND
      c.is_booked = :is_booked AND
      ct.trip_type_id =:trip_type_id AND
      ct.from_location_id =:from_location_id AND
      ct.to_location_id = :to_location_id AND
      c.from_date_time <= :to_date_time AND
      c.to_date_time >= :from_date_time;
```

Two periods overlap if the first starts before the second ends and the first ends after the first starts.  That seems to be the logic you want.

You should also be careful about `$car_category_id_list`.  You can't pass in the list as a parameter.

Comment: why are you change the parameter position ?

Comment: 'after the second starts'

Comment: @chiragpatel . . . So the logic is correct.  I believe I explain this in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

*Simply try this !*

SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2012-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-25 23:59:59'

Records [Between]
From : '2012-12-25 00:00:00'
To   : '2012-12-25 23:59:59'